ABNT BibLatex style adds ¡ and ¿ bracketing urls
When using the abnt style (defined, I believe, by the abntex2 class) in Biblatex, it consistently adds an inverted bang before any bibliography url and an inverted question mark after it.
Minimal code for the tex file:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    style = abnt,
    bibencoding = utf8,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Text

\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}

Minimal code for the .bib file
@article{article,
    author = {Someone Surname},
    title = {Title},
    journaltitle = {Journal},
    year = {2024},
    volume = {1},
    publisher = {Stack Exchange},
    location = {Earth},
    url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com},
    urldate = {2024-11-30},
}
@online{website,
    title = {Website},
    author = {Writer Lastname},
    publisher = {Stackexchange},
    location = {Terra},
    date = {2024-11-29},
    url = {https://www.stackexchange.com},
    urldate = {2024-11-30},
}

Results in the following reference page:

EDIT: The issue was encoding.

I can't reproduce the issue with the code you showed.
